# How to combine many parsers?

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, parsec

Why this parser fails and how to fix it?

```hs
λ> str1 = string "elif "
λ> str2 = string "else "
λ> strs = (,) <$> many str1 <*> optionMaybe str2
```

```hs
λ> parse strs "" "elif elif elif else "
Left (line 1, column 16):
unexpected "s"
expecting "elif "
```

How to combine a `many` parser and an `optionalMaybe` parser?

Comment: The problem is that `many` will keep "eating" `a`s, so the last one is never passed to your `a` in `<*> a`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I changed example. Parsers start from the same word. `many` shouldn't eat "else", but it does.

Comment: Use `try $ string "elif "` if you want to allow backtracking after it eats the first "e" and "l"

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks, it works! I'll mark your answer if you create it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `string "elif "` will eat the `el` in `else`, and since it has consumed input it will not backtrack and instead complain about an unexpected `s`

The easiest fix is to allow backtracking with `try`:

```
str1 = try $ string "elif "
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answer shows the easy fix using `try`. That does introduce a cost, though, namely the introduction of backtracking. In this answer I introduce another solution with no backtracking, and which therefore should be slightly faster and use slightly less memory. The basic idea is to parse the shared prefix, then dispatch once we hit the part where the two things actually differ. So:

```
strs = (string "el" *> (elseParser <|> elifParser)) <|> pure ([], Nothing) where
    elseParser = ([], Just "else ") <$ string "se "
    elifParser = liftA2
        (\_ (elifs, elses) -> ("elif ":elifs, elses))
        (string "if ")
        strs
```

For simplicity, I use constant `"else "` and `"elif "` strings in the results, but these can be built from the partial results of the `string` parsers with a bit of extra wiring.